# NoClassDefFound error in PDDocument when I tried running Eclipse java jar using JRuby

Tags: eclipse, jruby, noclassdeffounderror

I have written Java code that uses PDFbox to read text in a PDF and output the text. I've copied pdfbox-2.0.7.jar in a folder inside the project and built the path for this jar with respect to that folder. The project runs fine in Eclipse and command line.

However, when I use JRuby to call the method that reads PDF files, it throws the following error:

> Java::JavaLang::NoClassDefFoundError (org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument):
>     newproject1.NewProject1.ReadPDF(newproject1/NewProject1.java:33)

I'm getting this error in the following line of the code:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(fullFilename.toString()));
```

I'm using JRuby 9.0.1.0 and openjdk 8 in Ubuntu. I created jar file in Eclipse 3.8. I've also included "commons-logging-12.jar" as suggested by one of the answers on Stack Overflow but the issue persists.

I created a simple project and included a jar of same project inside that project. JRuby was able to access that but is throwing error when using PDFBox.

Comment: The pdfbox jar is *not* named PDFBox.jar. Get the file(s) here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi and make sure that they are in your classpath.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: I know that is not its name, I used that name to refer to the jar file of PDFBox. Made the change as you suggested by mentioning the correct official name. Also, I checked in .project file and the jar file is there in the classpath. Moreover, I read that NoClassDefFound error is regarding something else missing related to the jar but not the jar file itself. However, I'm unable to figure that out. In case you have any suggestion regarding that, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer: Saw the corrections made to my question and explanation. Thanks. I'll take care in future.